# Ternary operation of an incomplete statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining, ternary

Syntax question; is it possible to do the following:

```
var home_page_feed;
var videos = $get_utoob_videos;
for each(video in videos) {
    if(video.special_interests)
        $(home_page_feed).prepend(video.thumbnail);
    else
        $(home_page_feed).append(video.censornail);
}
```

...but in a **single** ternary operation, like this:

```
for each(video in videos)
    $(home_page_feed) .CHAIN. 
        video.special_interests ? 
             // true - chain this
            .prepend(video.thumbnail) :
             // false - chain this instead
            .append(video.censornail);
```

I put **.CHAIN.** as a placeholder. Is there a jQuery function that would chain to a incomplete statement by means of ternary operation assignment? I enjoy using ternary for statements and operations because of it's simplicity, so any help would be appreciated.

**ANSWER**
Thanks to @Barmar, who suggested the use of the eval() function, I was able to wrap it around the ternary operation.

```
$.each(videos, function(i, video) {
    eval ("$(home_page_feed)" +
        ((video.special_interest) ? 
            ".prepend(video.thumbnail)" :
            ".append(video.censornail)"
        )
    );
});
```

Comment: neither of those snippets are valid javascript to begin with - even without this .CHAIN. mystery item - but no, from the little I can discern of your code, you can't do that

Comment: The first one is valid under the right global; but you don't need to run it however, regarding the question.

Comment: `for each` - is that valid in some flavour of javascript? I must be having a stroke because I can't recall this syntax at all!!

Comment: @JaromandaX lol

Comment: @JaromandaX: It's a deprecated Mozilla-specific syntax. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in

Comment: thanks @squint - I was genuinely concerned for my well being :p

Comment: I meant valid under the right scope, not global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the ternary in the argument to `.append()`

```
$.each(videos, function(i, video) {
    $(home_page_feed).append(video.special_interests ? video.thumbnail : video.censornail);
});
```

Or you can put it in the index:

```
$.each(videos, function(i, video) {
    $(home_page_feed).append(video[video.special_interests ? "thumbnail" : "censornail"]);
});
```

Note the quotes in the last version.

You could do your code using `eval()`

```
$.each(videos, function(i, video) {
    var chain = video.special_interest ? 
        ".prepend(video.thumbnail)" :
        ".prepend(video.censornail)";
    eval ("$(home_page_feed)" + chain);
});
```

Comment: yeah thanks, am aware; awesome syntax. Not what I am asking  for but thanks for the cool trick. I'm thinking that what I'm trying to do is not possible?

Comment: Then I don't udnerstand what you're asking for. Your last loop makes no sense, because you're simply overwriting `chain` each time through the loop. Did you mean `chain +=`, so it would concatenate to it?

Comment: You can't create snippets of Javascript like that, and then execute them by concatenating.

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot to add backets. I just added them. But no, I'm using + to concat the string to the incomplete statement. This works because the concatenation becomes a complete statement at runtime.

Comment: You can't concatenate strings to partial statements. Javascript doesn't execute strings.

Comment: You could do what you want using `eval()`, but that's gross. But I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: I must be thinking of PHP then? Sorry, if that is the case; that example would be for PHP then. But my jQuery question still remains.....

Comment: PHP won't do what you want, either. No common language automatically executes statements just because you concatenate strings to code snippets. They all require you to do something special to get variable variables, variable methods, or call eval()

Comment: E.g. in PHP you can write `$object->$methodName()` to call the method named in the variable.

Comment: BTW, PHP uses `.` for concatenation, not `+`. You're really confused about things.

Comment: It works in PHP. But lets not get caught up in that last example.

Comment: Thanks, definitely like your eval() suggestion, unfortunately it is 2 statements. But it can be simplified to 1, see my modification above.

Comment: You're welcome, although I still don't understand why you're trying to do it this way. The `eval` method is clearly inferior to the versions that just execute code normally, since it can't be compiled.

Comment: yea kinda of just a syntax nerd question.. maybe useful for code golf.. What do you mean "compiled"? JS is an interpreted language.

Comment: oh wow, double interpretation.. https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/

Comment: @Jim22150 Javascript uses a JIT compiler.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up on my explicit statements from string concatonation.. The way I was doing that was I was writing to json in one script and later loading the json in another script... Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This should be helpful

```
var home_page_feed;
var videos = $get_utoob_videos;
for each(video in videos) {
  (video.special_interests)?$(home_page_feed).prepend(video.thumbnail): $(home_page_feed).append(video.censornail);


}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks but I'm hoping to chain to an incomplete statement as an operation. Your's is not an operation and has 2 complete statements; which is the reason I would like to simplify the syntax so you don't have to write $(home_page_feed) twice.